# React Query useMutation set mutationKey dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, react-query

In my React project using React Query, I have a functional component `MoveKeywordModal` such that:

1. when it first loads, it fetches from API endpoint `api/keyword_lists` to fetch a bunch of `keywordLists` data. For each of these `keywordLists`, call it `list`, I create a clickable element.
2. When the clickable element (wrapped in a `HoverWrapper`) gets clicked, I want to send a POST API request to `api/keyword_lists/:list_id/keyword_list_items/import` with some data.
   where `:list_id` is the id of the list just  clicked.

```
export const MoveKeywordModal = ({
  setShowMoveKeywordModal,
  keywordsToMove
}) => {
  const { data: keywordLists } = useQuery('api/keyword_lists', {})
  const [newKeywordList, setNewKeywordList] = useState({})
  const { mutate: moveKeywordsToList } = useMutation(
    `api/keyword_lists/${newKeywordList.id}/keyword_list_items/import`,
    {
      onSuccess: data => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  )
  const availableKeywordLists = keywordLists
    .filter(l => l.id !== activeKeywordList.id)
    .map(list => (
      <HoverWrapper
        id={list.id}
        onClick={() => {
          setNewKeywordList(list)
          moveKeywordsToList({
            variables: { newKeywordList, data: keywordsToMove }
          })
        }}>
        <p>{list.name}</p>
      </HoverWrapper>
    ))

  return (
    <>
      <StyledModal
        isVisible
        handleBackdropClick={() => setShowMoveKeywordModal(false)}>
        <div>{availableKeywordLists}</div>
      </StyledModal>
    </>
  )
}
```

Despite calling `setNewKeywordList(list)` in the `onClick` of the `HoverWrapper`, it seems the `newKeywordList.id` is still not defined, not even `newKeywordList` is defined.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react doesn’t perform state updates immediately when you call the setter of `useState` - an update is merely 'scheduled'. So even though you call `setNewKeywordList`, the `newKeywordList` will not have the new value in the next line of code - only in the next render cycle.

So while you are in your event handler, you’ll have to use the `list` variable:

```
setNewKeywordList(list)
moveKeywordsToList({
    variables: { newKeywordList: list, data: keywordsToMove }
 })
```

/edit: I just realized that your call to `useMutation` is not correct. It doesn’t have a `key` like `useQuery`, it has to provide a function as the first argument that takes variables, known as the mutation function:

```
  const { mutate: moveKeywordsToList } = useMutation(
    (variables) => axios.post(`api/keyword_lists/${variables.newKeywordList.id}/keyword_list_items/import`),
    {
      onSuccess: data => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  )
```

see also: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, it is still making an API call to `api/keyword_lists/undefined/keyword_list_items/import`, rather than getting the `newKeywordList` variable's `id` attribute and using it.

Comment: I amended my answer by- i missed that the call of useMutation was not correct

Comment: Thanks, we're definitely getting there! By doing

```

const { mutate: moveKeywordsToList } = useMutation(
    variables =>
      `api/keyword_lists/${variables.newKeywordList.id}/keyword_list_items/import`,
    {
      onSuccess: data => {
        console.log('on success')
        console.log(data)
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  )
```
I am building the correct url, e.g. `api/keyword_lists/1/keyword_list_items/import`

However, the API call was never made and it seems to call `onSuccess` handler directly and the url above.

Comment: Yes, the mutation function needs to actually do a post or put request, e.g. via axios.post. Please look at the linked examples